# Macbook Aluminum wakes up - Lion Updated

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, sleep-wake

I have recently updated my macbook with Lion. Now it keeps on waking up in my bag for some unknown reason. Here is what i get in the console.

`An Unknown USB Device (Port 4 of Hub at 0x4000000), may have caused a wake by being connected`

I'm not sure what is at the port 4 of Hub? Also what i have discovered is that my bluetooth module apparently is not connected!? **What would cause this to happen?**

This is from system info:

```
USB Bus:

  Host Controller Location: Built-in USB
  Host Controller Driver:   AppleUSBOHCI
  PCI Device ID:    0x0aa5 
  PCI Revision ID:  0x00b1 
  PCI Vendor ID:    0x10de 
  Bus Number:   0x04 

Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad:

  Product ID:   0x0236
  Vendor ID:    0x05ac  (Apple Inc.)
  Version:  0.77
  Speed:    Up to 12 Mb/sec
  Manufacturer: Apple, Inc.
  Location ID:  0x04600000 / 3

IR Receiver:

  Product ID:   0x8242
  Vendor ID:    0x05ac  (Apple Inc.)
  Version:  0.16
  Speed:    Up to 1.5 Mb/sec
  Manufacturer: Apple Computer, Inc.
  Location ID:  0x04500000 / 2
```

How do I find what is at port 4? Could it be bluetooth module?

Comment: If you look in System Information, you might be able to see what that device is.

Comment: @jtbandes updated question.

Comment: Have you tried restarting your computer?

Comment: @jtbandes I have restarted it many times, i even reinstalled OSX from scratch now. So its fully stock.

Comment: I have ordered a replacement for monitor data cable - as i have also discovered that iSight is not working - since those both work on same cable I'll replace that and see how I go.